# OpenJDK that includes JavaFX, including WebView

Tags: javafx, jdk

Standard OpenJDK-11-JDK of Raspbian doesn't have JavaFX. BellSoft build does have JavaFX but does not support WebView (Webkit). How to be able to use WebView on the Pi (4 in this case with Buster)?

Comment: any reason you can't just use openjdk and download the arm package of javafx?

Comment: @abel There is no compatible arm package that includes webview/kit.